# How to visualize several groups of points?

Tags: plotting, cluster-analysis

I have generated a dataset that clustered some of data points into three groups, the output was three -column data like this:

[image]

there are some points with X,Y coordinates and I already labeled each of them the group number (from 1-3).

As I want to visualize the result by demonstrating those points on a Cartesian plane, for each group of points using the different color so that people can see the clustering result clearly. Something like this below that plotted by Mathematica `ListPlot[FindCluster[]]`:

[image]

(this pic has showed four groups of data (so 4 types of color), in my case, i just need three kind of whatever color)

I've used `Riffle[]` and `Partition[]` to pair the points' x,y coordinates accordingly. So by `ListPlot[]` them you can see those points are landing correctly:

[image]

So basically I came up with Mathematica when I firstly had some thinking about demonstrating my result. But the tricky part is how could I show different colors for each group. Looks like `FindCluster[]` could do the most of the part job like this (or I could be wrong), but I might still need one or two more steps to color the points according to my group labels.

Please feel free to leave your comment, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have your points labeled by group, I'm not totally sure I understand how [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) is helpful here, but please correct me if I've missed something.

In any case, you can split up the data into separate lists (by group). [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) will color points in different lists differently (and of course, you can customize the styling):

```
data = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
     RandomInteger[{1, 3}]} & /@ Range[100];

gathered = GatherBy[data, #[[3]] &];

ListPlot[
 #[[All, 1 ;; 2]] & /@ gathered,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
 ]
```

[image: ListPlot]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, you are right, if the group is labeled, no need for the FindClusters at this stage. Just ListPlot the groups, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

For example, data in form $\{...,\{x_i,y_i,lbl_i\},...\}$.

Dummy data:

```
data = Join @@ 
   MapIndexed[Function[{u}, Append[u, #2[[1]]]] /@ #1 &, 
    RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[#, {1, 1}, 0.03], 100] & /@ 
     RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {4, 2}]];
```

Visualization:

```
g = KeySort[GroupBy[data, Last, #[[All, {1, 2}]] &]];
With[{k = Keys[g]}, ListPlot[k /. g, PlotLegends -> k]]
```

[image]